# gem rest_in_place and alias_attribute issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model that is connecting to a legacy database using active record. Because the column names are in all caps. I have created alias_attributes for them like so

```
alias_attribute(:marketing_code, :MARKETING_CODE)
```

Unfortunatley when I am using the rest_in_place gem the returned JSON only includes the original column names.  This results in the rest_in_place to never return the written value back and it just says saving....  but the update is made.

This is what my view code looks like

```
   <span id="fund_<%= fund.id %>_MARKETING_CODE" class="rest-in-place" data-url="/funds/<%= fund.id %>" data-object="fund" data-attribute="MARKETING_CODE">
            <%= fund.MARKETING_CODE.blank? ? 'Fill In' : fund.MARKETING_CODE %>
          </span>
```

Is there any way to make it work with an attribute alias? I would prefer to use them so I can follow ruby standards.  Below is the README for rest_in_place

http://rubydoc.info/gems/rest_in_place/2.1.1/frames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my issue and hopefully this will help others when using alias_attribute with ActiveRecord it does not effect the responding JSON.

I noticed this by reviewing the Network tab within chrome developer tools. In my specific case I was using the alias_attribute to change a legacy database column from upper_case to lower_case to fit within the rails code style guide.  Unfortunately upon reviewing the responding JSON I saw the attributes were being returned as UPPERCASE.

So for those using rest_in_place with a legacy database it will only respond to the actual column name.  If someone knows of a work around I would be grateful.